# How to write input register in Raspberry Pi 3 using pymodbus

Tags: python, modbus, modbus-tcp

I have a python code here to read input register and it is working, but it doesn't display the register in HMI Droid Studio appliaction. Here is the code:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient
import time
Kanban1 = 0
#Open TCP Port
#client = Modbus ('192.168.43.136')
client = ModbusClient ('192.168.4.189')

client.connect()

rq = client.write_register(0,100)
try:
    while True:
        rr = client.read_holding_registers(0,50)
        print rr.registers
        if(rr.registers[Kanban1] < 100):
            print "Reading Registers"
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        client.close()
        print "Finish"
```

any help is appreciated 
Thank you

Comment: You need to check your HMI code to see why the HMI is not updating . How are you using the pymodbus client in your HMI application ?

Answer (score 1):

Some HMIs default to a 1 based register number linking to the 0 based modbus register number, try setting/using register 1 instead of zero